# improving scala code compilation time in Intellij IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Iam in the process of learning Scala using IntelliJ IDEA 10.0.x with scala plugin and I have found that compiling scala takes more than 10 secs. I know there is a an option to turn on the fast code compilation (FSC) in scala however Iam unaware of how to configure that in IDEA is there any option available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After create a scala project in IDEA go Run/Edit Configurations:

1. Click in +
2. Select Scala Compilation Server, and
   give a name to this configuration.
3. Now press run.

Answer (score 6):

After reading "[Why does IntelliJ IDEA compile Scala so slowly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606591/why-does-intellij-idea-compile-scala-so-slowly)", I would rather use IntelliJ IDEA [with sbt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972006/whats-the-best-scala-build-system/972822#972822):

- [idea-sbt plugin](https://github.com/orfjackal/idea-sbt-plugin): for using the SBT Console tool window to enter SBT commands directly.

Note that [sbt cannot use fsc either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624597/sbt-and-the-fast-scala-compiler) (in interactive mode).