# How to use fsc with sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt, scalac, scala-compiler, fsc

Related question: [Does SBT use the Fast Scala Compiler (fsc)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624597/does-sbt-use-the-fast-scala-compiler-fsc)

Can fsc be used with sbt; would it be practical; and if so, how to integrate fsc into sbt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fsc cannot be used with sbt.

https://github.com/sbt/sbt/wiki/Client-server-split shows that the sbt team is currently working in a similar/related direction. They're turning sbt itself into a local compile server — like fsc but better. I wouldn't be surprised if once they're done, fsc is deprecated and removed from Scala. (fsc has never worked all that well or been very actively maintained.)